# KDE custom global shortcuts

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I set a global shortcut in KDE (4.4) to run a bash script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First make sure that your script is executable, e.g. like this

```
chmod +x ~/scripts/myscript.sh
```

Then create the shortcut using the tool which can be accessed by System Settings > Input Actions. Do a right click in the left pane where existing shortcuts are listed and say New Global Shortcut > Command/URL. Set the name to something sensible, choose your desired shortcut, set the command to your script, e.g. ~/scripts/myscript.sh and tick the Enabled box. If you put your script in a folder in path, (following common conventions one would use /usr/local/bin) you can skip the path in the command and just write myscript.sh.

Comment: I can not find input actions (using debian jessie, kde 4.14.2)

Comment: In Wheezy and Jessie it seems to be: System Settings →shortcuts and gestures →Custom shortcuts » edit →new →global shortcuts → command/url (maybe for all other systems using newer KDE).  Why they hid it?, We may never know. (I just realised that I have just answered my own comment.)